# Create Rails Association with different column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have three models namely, Notifications, Devices and Users.
Notification has `registration_ids` which is mapped to the `token` field of devices. Devices has `user_id` field which is mapped to the `id` field of User model.

How do I create as has_many_through or has_and_belongs_to_many association from Notification model to extract the user corresponding to that notification.

Moreover, I created this association in Notifications class `belongs_to :device, :primary_key => 'registration_ids', :foreign_key => 'token'` and this one in device class `has_many :notifications, :primary_key => 'token', :foreign_key => 'registration_ids'`

device class is able to recognize the notification class, while notification class is not able to recognize the device class

Following the piece of my code from notification.rb file

```
class Notification < Rpush::Gcm::Notification
  self.inheritance_column = nil
  belongs_to :device, :foreign_key => 'registration_ids', :primary_key => 'token'
  delegate :user, to: :device #-> notification.user.name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#app/models/notification.rb
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device, foreign_key: :registration_id, primary_key: :token
  delegate :user, to: :device #-> notification.user.name
end

#app/models/device.rb
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :registration_id, primary_key: :token
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
  has_many :notifications, through: :devices
end
```

The above is how I would perceive it to be set up.

You'll be able to call:

```
@notification = Notification.find params[:id]

@notification.device.user.name #-> "name" of associated "user" model
@notification.user.name        #-> delegate to "user" model directly
```

---

The [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method is a trick to circumvent the [`law of demeter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) issue (calling an object several levels "away" from the parent).

Comment: getting the following error `2.2.1 :071 > Notification.last.device  
  Notification Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "rpush_notifications".* FROM "rpush_notifications"  ORDER BY "rpush_notifications"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
TypeError: can't cast Array to string
`

Comment: Interesting. Do you have some context? I don't know how you're getting to that result -- can you show me the `console` log for the request as as screenshot?

Comment: Okay. Your `registration_ids` column is causing issues. You're only mean to store a single piece of data in each cell; you either have an array, or a Ruby collection. You need to get rid of it

Comment: I can chat if you need more help

Comment: Registration ids field is configured as an array in the Rpush gem itself, i can't change it

Comment: Really? Are you available to chat?